# Saving list of values from pandas dataframe to SQL dababase

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, sqlite

I have a dataframe which I would like to save to sqlite3 database. df format

```
                 name                                         actor_link                                     list_of_movies
0  'Weird Al' Yankovic  https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/30382-weird-al-yank...  [https://www.csfd.cz/film/10197-blazniva-strel...
1              50 Cent          https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/26636-50-cent/  [https://www.csfd.cz/film/373150-straight-outt...
2       A'Ali de Sousa  https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/234765-a-ali-de-sousa/  [https://www.csfd.cz/film/248568-jmenuji-se-kh...
3            A-Ping On         https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/9799-a-ping-on/  [https://www.csfd.cz/film/136427-zrada-a-pomsta/]
4     A. Gerald Singer  https://www.csfd.cz/tvurce/470414-a-gerald-sin...         [https://www.csfd.cz/film/9795-stalag-17/]
```

columns `name` and `actor_link` are string data type, but `list_of_movies` is list
when I try to save it to db

```
def _actors_to_db(actor_dataframe, longest_row):
    con = sqlite3.connect("example.db") # test
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actors
            (`name` varchar(255), `actor_link` varchar(255), `movie_links` varchar(longest_row)
        """)
    con.commit()
    actor_dataframe.to_sql('actors', con, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    print("Actors saved to db!")
```

I get always error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

is it because of the data type? how can I load it to db? and how can I set `longest_row` parametr to sql query (I have it in int format

```
s = actor_df['list_of_movies'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
    max_length = s.str.len().max()
```

)?

Comment: The `movie_links` column in the database is a string, but `list_of_movies` in your dataframe is a list.

Comment: You shouldn't put a comma-separated list in a database column. You should normalize the tables, with each URL in a separate row of another table that uses a foreign key.

Comment: Can I save list to db? Is there any SQL data type for it or I have to change it in df to string?

Comment: You have to change it to a string. But see my second comment.

Comment: "But see my second comment." thx for this one as well. Actually this is original structure i had it stored in csv file